# Why does passing tokio_postgres::Transaction as a reference ask to indicate the anonymous lifetime?

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-tokio

I'm using tokio_postgres to connect to a database and trying to start a transaction

```
let trans = client.transaction().await.unwrap();
trans.query("select * from abc", &[]).await.unwrap();
// ...
trans.commit().await.unwrap();
```

Everything works as expected. Now I want to put the code between `trans.query` and `trans.commit` into a separate function

```
async fn tx_work(trans: &tokio_postgres::Transaction) {
    trans.query("select * from abc", &[]).await.unwrap();
    // ...
    trans.commit().await.unwrap();
}
```

and call it in `main`:

```
let trans = client.transaction().await.unwrap();
tx_work(&trans).await.unwrap();
```

The code doesn't compile:

```
error[E0726]: implicit elided lifetime not allowed here
   --> src/abc.rs:209:28
    |
209 | async fn tx_work(trans: &tokio_postgres::Transaction) {
    |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^- help: indicate the anonymous lifetime: `<'_>`
```

This didn't help:

```
async fn tx_work<'a>(trans: &'a tokio_postgres::Transaction)
```

What do I do?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: I edited the question and included the entire error message.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the definition of [`Transaction`](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.5.4/tokio_postgres/struct.Transaction.html) it seems you want the lifetime  specifier/parameter on the struct itself, not on the function parameter reference:

```
async fn tx_work(trans: &tokio_postgres::Transaction<'_>)
```

That's using the anonymous lifetime, but you can also explicitly specify the lifetime parameter:

```
async fn tx_work<'a>(trans: &tokio_postgres::Transaction<'a>)
```

<sup>It is common to relate these lifetimes to other existing lifetimes, for example, if you already had an explicit lifetime elsewhere and it makes sense to do so, you might pass it as the parameter directly.</sup>

This is because `tokio_postgres::Transaction` does not fully specify the type anymore than `Vec` would (compared to `Vec<u8>`), i.e. the lifetime specifiers are part of the type name, so you need `tokio_postgres::Transaction<'some_lifetime>`, but apparently you can use the anonymous lifetime `'_` too.

More specifically, here, the lifetime parameter on `Transaction` pertains to the lifetime of the references contained within the `Transaction` struct, whereas a lifetime on the *reference* to the `Transaction` struct (like you initially attempted) pertains to … well, the lifetime of that very reference.

If this is all still confusing, I encourage you to read the excellent [chapter on lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html) from the book. It is an integral part of the Rust programming paradigm.

Comment: This answer would be improved by discussing why the compiler gives this error.

Comment: Jorge, thanks, it works, but honestly I don't know why. It will be really helpful if you can explain the answer a bit more, why `&tokio_postgres::Transaction<'_>` is a ref on struct `Transaction` while `&tokio_postgres::Transaction` is a ref on the ref to the struct?

Comment: That's my fault, I just realized I used confusing language. What I meant was, where you needed the lifetime specifier `<'lifetime>` is on the type `Transaction`, i.e. `Transaction<'lifetime>`, you can liken it to how `Vec` on its own isn't a type (yet), but something like `Vec<String>` is, in other words, `Transaction` on its own is incomplete. I meant to say that `Transaction` is where you needed to add the lifetime parameter, not on the reference function parameter like you initially attempted.

Comment: To make things more concrete, you use either `<'_>` (the anonymous lifetime) or you explicitly specify a lifetime parameter, I'll add that to my answer.